# Capistrano 2 - Pass array arguments to a Rake task

Tags: ruby, rake, capistrano

I am trying to write a Rake task in my `deploy.rb` that gets passed an array of arguments. I will run it through capistrano.

Assuming a task like the following:

```
desc "my task"
task :mytask, [:arguments] => :environment do |t, args|
  puts 'hello'
end
```

When I try running `cap mytask['arg1 arg2 arg3']`, I get the following:

```
the task `mytask["arg1 arg2 arg3"]' does not exist
```

Any ideas? I have a task defined like this that I run locally with no problems, but defining tasks like this be run using `cap` does not work.

NOTE: running `cap mytask` without the arguments part works. This is obviously not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Rake tasks are defined by a string and called via Rake::Task["name"] internally . If cap treats your array as part of the task name string it will not work.

As `'mytask' != 'mytask["arg1 arg2 arg3"]'`

Comment: sorry that i can't help you further, hoped i can lead you in the right direction by giving you the reason it (probably) fails. You could look for another way to pass parameters to a capistrano task.

Comment: @n_x_l there is also a good possibility that capistrano 2 does not support that rake feature. I found that Capistrano 3 should support it that way, but couldn't find any source if 2 also does. The source code is so different that it's highly possible it doesnt.